# Measure query execution time in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, time, query

I need to measure a query total execution time from inside a bash script.

Somebody told me to submit something like:

```
mysql --user="someuser" --password="pw" -D "dbname" -e 'your-sql-command;'
```

Is it right?

But how can I get the timing stats I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`time`

as in

```
tom.oconnor@charcoal-black:/tmp$ time ls -lah
total 20K
drwxrwxrwt 26 root        root    4.0K 2012-04-11 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root        root    4.0K 2012-04-03 15:01 ..


real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Cool, huh?

From the `time` manpage

```
TIME(1)                                  TIME(1)

NAME
       time - run programs and summarize system resource usage
```

Comment: note however, that the time manpage documents /usr/bin/time and running time as you did is using the shell command modifier (assuming something like bash or zsh) (try `which time` or `type time`)

Comment: in bash you'd get the help for the time modifier with `help time`